# How to vertically align the baseline of text to a set point in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created an algorithm that converts text formatted in SVG into HTML, the algorithm works well but the positioning of the text in the HTML version is slightly out compared to the SVG.

I have realised that this is due to the coordinate system in SVG; it's origin is at the bottom left rather than the top left.  Therefore my HTML text is below the position it should be.  This is for commercial software, personally I would rather keep the text as SVG, but I can't because of a client request, also this needs to be a pixel perfect copy!

In order to fix the HTML I need to align the text so that its baseline is at the point that I read from the SVG.  I have tried to do this with vertical-alignment but with no success.

The problem is not working out the coordinates here, I already know where the baseline of the text should be.

Does anyone know how to to align the baseline of some text to a set point in HTML?  Or does anyone know if it is even possible to place text using the baseline rather than the top left point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS can't change the position of the baseline. It is where it is, based on the font.

> I would love
>   to do this by trial an error but this needs to work for any SVG file,
>   which could use any font, at any size. Therefore the margin is going
>   to be different each time.

That rules out any kind of "hack" to make it look right..

Take a look at all the possible values for [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).

If none of those help, I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: Cheers, this is what I expected to be the case.  I am not a web dev but every now and again I have to do something that involves HTML.  It always surprises me how clunky it is.

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround**

One way will be to wrap your fonts in an element to allow vertically nudging it in the viewport.

```html
<style>
.font-vertical-fix {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -0.2em;
}
</style>

<span class="font-vertical-fix">
  Some badly designed font family ported to the web.
</span>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rkc3ho48/

**Solution**

The solution is to use a Webfont that's designed for the web.

Not all fonts made for desktop apps like Adobe/Sketch are designed with the web in mind. On these platforms, the designer can just vertically nudge the font in the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

line-height should work for you. But to be honest, your going to need to play around with a few things, like padding, margin to get it just right.

Comment: I am struggling to see how? I need to line the baseline of the text to a set point.  I would love to do this by trial an error but this needs to work for any SVG file, which could use any font, at any size.  Therefore the margin is going to be different each time.

Comment: There is no way to do it pixel perfect programmatically. Once you have subtracted the line-height you need to see how many pixels it is off and compensate by that amount. It will be different for each font and worse even the same font will be different on different systems and in different versions.

Comment: Just to elaborate - the "how many pixels it is off" is the distance from the bottom of the line-height to the baseline in this font. There is no way to programmatically get this value from a browser, and it is different for each font.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to define the location using divs bottom and left (or whatever you have each line of text set as) CSS properties (and make sure that it's position is set to absolute).

Comment: The problem isn't placing the DIV, it is aligning the text's baseline to a specific point point.

Comment: Well then the best you're going to be able to do is make sure no padding, no margin, set the line height, etc. and place that div because there is no way to get 100% picture perfect on the text itself.